# PHP's IF/Else for a Login display

Tags: php, security, if-statement, authentication

My goal is to have as if the IF states to display the "Welcome, %USERNAME%" which links to that person's account settings. The issue is, as I see it, is not displaying it if they are NOT logged in. I would like that to be "Please Login" link instead.

```
<?php 

 require("common.php"); 

 if (session_start()) {
     echo '<p class="right"><a href="/account"><?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a>!</p>';
     }
 else {
      echo '<p class="right"><a href="">Please Login</a></p>';
      }
```

My issue is with the IF/Else that it is not correct... what am I doing wrong or forgetting... ?

Comment: Doesn't PHP create (or resume) a persistent session when you call `session_start()`, regardless of the context? I think you should be checking to see if the current session has a logged-in identifier.

Comment: You probably had some output before `session_start()` which makes the function return false. Hence your `else` clause is triggered. Is error reporting enabled?

Comment: [`session_start()` just starts the session nothing more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php). Also you need to [concatenate the string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). When in doubt please consult the manual: http://php.net/manual/en

Comment: Haha, out of all of my mistakes I could make... -.-'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You approach is wrong, you need to have `session_start()` at the very top of the page, than use a session variable like this

```
$_SESSION['is_logged_in'] = false;
```

Now when the user is logged in change the value to `true` and again to `false` when user logs out

So now you can set a condition like

```
if($_SESSION['is_logged_in'] == true) {
   echo 'Welcome';
} else {
   echo 'Please login';
}
```

On the other hand you can also redirect the users to login page if they are not logged in using `header()`

So for example if you don't want user to see a page called `admin.php` than on that page at the very top you can specify the condition, if it's false you can redirect

admin.php

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['is_logged_in'] == false) {
    header('Location: login.php'); 
    /* You can replace login.php to whatever page you want your 
       user to be redirected */
    exit;
}
```

Comment: How can I pull the username from the database for when they are logged in too? That is where my issue is coming up with my Else statement.

Comment: You need to check the username/password combination, if it matches, select required fields you want using a query and than store the data in session var, like `$_SESSION['username'] = ` and than you can echo this anywhere you want

Answer (score 4):

```
if (session_start()) {
```

should be

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['user']['username'])) {
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Although this might be a better way of actually doing this, this doesn't take `session_start()`'s return value in to consideration.

Comment: Thanks, but in case `session_start` returns `FALSE`, user will always see Login link, which is the expected behavior. This is also complemented by the fact that no examples at `PHP session_start()` manual look for return value of it